# The most opposite word of "the largest"

Tags: superlative-degree, ielts

When we compare **numbers of people**, we can use the phrases:

- "The **`highest/lowest`** number of people was"
- "The **`biggest/smallest`** number of people was"
- "The **`most/least`** people were"

That the word **`"lowest"`** is an antonym for the word **`"highest"`**.

---

What is an antonym of the word **`"largest"`** when we compare **numbers of people**?

> - **"The **`largest/_________`** number of people was"**

*Is it the word **`"tiniest"`**?
But number of usage times on google is quite **[low](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=%22the+tiniest+number+of%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enTH771TH771&oq=%22the+tiniest+number+of%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.8183j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)***

Comment: To follow Ian, why do you feel that smallest doesn't fit?

Comment: I thought **"smallest"** was already with **"biggest"**. Isn't there any other words? @Unrelated

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84879/discussion-on-question-by-hbtpoprock-the-most-opposite-word-of-the-largest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly tricky. Same quantifiers can be used to describe different 
items. For example: 'largest' can refer to size and also number. In your question, we can write

> The largest/**smallest** number of people was

Again, 'tiniest' cannot make any sense because we are talking about 'number' of people here.

Comment: Best to avoid <pre> blocks in posts. They often cause horizontal scrollbars which chop off text, making the post very hard to read.

Answer (score -3):

The suggestions are about right. I believe Largest may not be the right descriptor of the number. A number would be greater than, or the greatest. This would correspond to another being less than, or the least.

Comment: Numbers are very often described as being large or small, so I'm not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Hi Elliot, welcome to English Language & Usage. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference hyperlinked to the source. This helps differentiate an *answer* from an unsubstantiated *opinion*. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)